# C code for date time format validation. specified format is "YYYYMMDDHHMMSSmmmmmm"

Tags: c, datetime, validation, datetime-format

I need to validate a date-time value for "`YYYYMMDDHHMMSSmmmmmm`" format. Actually what I am hoping is I need to find out a already tested working C code to validate a date time value for above format.
Further, I have a date-time value like `201304011031000000`. I need a function to verify whether this is a valid date or not.[`isdatetime()`]

Below are the each parts of formats.

```
YYYY : Year
MM : Month
DD : Day
HH : hour
MM : Minutes
SS : seconds
mmmmmm: micro-seconds
```

Comment: What is the `M` in `MSSSSS`?  And you have 5 digits for milliseconds?  If `M` is a digit too, then you'd have 6 fractional digits for microseconds; you only need three digits for milliseconds.  What binary format do you expect to get this data into?  `struct timeval`?  `struct timespec`?  Something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a POSIX system, this looks like something that should be handled with [`strptime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strptime.html), but the 'milliseconds' (or microseconds) part is not handled by `strptime()` or any other standard conversion function I know of.

Assuming the question is asking for microseconds, you could use a variation on the theme provided by:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char  datetime[] = "20130417221633012345"; // YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFFFFFF
    struct tm   time_val;
    unsigned    microsecs;
    const char *end = strptime(datetime, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", &time_val);
    if (end != 0)
    {
        int nbytes;
        if (strlen(end) == 6 && sscanf(end, "%6u%n", &microsecs, &nbytes) == 1 &&
            nbytes == 6)
        {
            char buffer[32];
            strftime(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &time_val);
            printf("%s = %s.%.6u\n", datetime, buffer, microsecs);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

#### Revised requirement

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int isdatetime(const char *datetime)
{
    // datetime format is YYYYMMDDHHMMSSFFFFFF
    struct tm   time_val;
    unsigned    microsecs;
    int         nbytes;
    const char *end = strptime(datetime, "%Y%m%d%H%M%S", &time_val);

    if (end != 0 && strlen(end) == 6 &&
        sscanf(end, "%6u%n", &microsecs, &nbytes) == 1 && nbytes == 6)
        return 1;   // Valid
    return 0;       // Invalid
}
```

Comment: Actually what I need to do is, I already have a date-time value like "20130417221633012345" in your code. I need to validate this value to verify whether it is a valid date time value or not. your code is very understandable for me and can you please focus on my aim.
Thanks & Regards.

Comment: The missing `else` clause for the two `if` statements are where you can detect and report errors.  You might, or might not, want to be lenient about digits missing from the microseconds. But by writing or otherwise reporting an error in those missing `else` clauses, you get the error handling you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regex.h` for [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230905/regex-h-for-windows) or for [linux](http://linux.die.net/man/3/regex).

`"YYYYMMDDHHMMSSMSSSSS"` is something like: `(\d{4}[0,1][0,9]\d{})...` you can find your specific format [here](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=4&categoryId=5&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), it depends wether you enable `24` or `12` clock etc.