# How do I get PCRE to work correctly with Code::blocks?

Tags: c++, regex, windows, codeblocks

I am facing some problems while working with PCRE in Code::blocks. I have downloaded PCRE from [here](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/pcre.htm). And did all the steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230905/regex-h-for-windows). However I am getting a pcr3.dll missing error during execution.

> The program can't start because pcre3.dll is missing from your
>   computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.

[My code](http://ideone.com/A3RTBt):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex.h>
using namespace std;


 int main(){

 regex_t reg;

 string pattern = "[^tpr]{2,}";
 string str = "topcoder";

 regmatch_t matches[1];

 regcomp(&reg,pattern.c_str(),REG_EXTENDED|REG_ICASE);

 if (regexec(&reg,str.c_str(),1,matches,0)==0) {
       cout << "Match " ;
       cout << str.substr(matches[0].rm_so,matches[0].rm_eo-matches[0].rm_so) ;
       cout << " found starting at: " ;
       cout << matches[0].rm_so ;
       cout << " and ending at " ;
       cout << matches[0].rm_eo ;
       cout << endl;
  } else {
       cout << "Match not found.";
       cout << endl;
 }
 regfree(&reg);

  return 0;
 }
```

I am not sure how to fix this, any ideas?

PS: Above mentioned code is taken from [this](http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=regularExpressions) tutorial.

Comment: Just double-checking, but did you read [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230905/regex-h-for-windows#comment10140086_8231041) in the post you linked to?  The error message you receive leads me to wonder (a) where `pcr3.dll` is located on your filesystem and (b) whether you have added the necessary include and lib paths in Code::Blocks' settings.  (That is, have you provided Code::Blocks with the path to the directory containing `pcr3.dll`?)

Comment: Yes, I did. I have linked the folder containing `pcr3.dll` in Search directories.

Comment: Hmm...did you also add `pcre3.dll` to the list of libraries to link against?  (I don't use Code::Blocks, but it would be [step 5B in this tutorial](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/a3-using-libraries-with-codeblocks/).)  It sounds like maybe you added the directory containing `pcre3.dll` to the linker search path (which is good), but failed to specify the library itself.  You might also try asking on forums.codeblocks.org.

Answer (score 1):

Copy the DLL to the same directory as the executable that you are running. If that works, you didn't install the DLL correctly or at least not in a way that it can be found by the programs in general. Check out the documentation of the [DLL Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get an idea how else you can make the system find the DLL. In particular, you need to know that there is a linker and a loader (aka dynamic/runtime linker/loader), but only one of them is configured inside CodeBlocks!