# gcc: fatal error: regex.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c, regex, gcc

For my C programs, I am using `gcc`.

Ultimately, I want to write a program that does stuff with regular expressions. Right now, however, my program simply outputs `Hello World`:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <regex.h>

int main(void) {

    printf("Hello World\n", regex);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's how I compiled that program:

```
gcc -std=c99 -o helloWorld helloWorld.c
```

That produces this error:

```
fatal error: regex.h: No such file or directory
```

I'm a C newbie. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What OS are you using? Do you have the standard library headers installed?

Comment: C99 doesn't have regex.h.

Comment: There is no "regex.h" in the standard C library. I think POSIX has one.

Comment: I am using Windows 7. How/where do I obtain the POSIX stuff?

Comment: IIRC Microsoft dropped POSIX-support with Windows XP. However, if you compiler is VC, that is not even C99 compliant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781211/c-regex-library-with-mingw , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8230905/regex-h-for-windows

Comment: <regex.h> is not standard C header file. Your code is meant to be C++, where <regex.h> is a valid header. Use g++ (and a .cpp file extension) for C++ code.

Answer (score -4):

See what happens if you drop .h from regex.h

Comment: That might work for C++, but usually not for C