# Specific place where I can download a include file that has regex.h in it

Tags: c, regex, ide, codeblocks

Currently I've been experiencing certain problems whenever I build code on Codeblocks.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <regex.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_MATCHES 1 //The maximum number of matches allowed in a single string

void match(regex_t *pexp, char *sz) {
    regmatch_t matches[MAX_MATCHES]; //A list of the matches in the string (a list of 1)
    //Compare the string to the expression
    //regexec() returns 0 on match, otherwise REG_NOMATCH
    if (regexec(pexp, sz, MAX_MATCHES, matches, 0) == 0) {
        printf("\"%s\" matches characters %d - %d\n", sz, matches[0].rm_so, matches[0].rm_eo);
    } else {
        printf("\"%s\" does not match\n", sz);
    }
}

int main() {
    int rv;
    regex_t exp; //Our compiled expression
    //1. Compile our expression.
    //Our regex is "-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?". I will explain this later.
    //REG_EXTENDED is so that we can use Extended regular expressions
    rv = regcomp(&exp, "-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?", REG_EXTENDED);
    if (rv != 0) {
        printf("regcomp failed with %d\n", rv);
    }
    //2. Now run some tests on it
    match(&exp, "0");
    match(&exp, "0.");
    match(&exp, "0.0");
    match(&exp, "10.1");
    match(&exp, "-10.1");
    match(&exp, "a");
    match(&exp, "a.1");
    match(&exp, "0.a");
    match(&exp, "0.1a");
    match(&exp, "hello");
    //3. Free it
    regfree(&exp);
    return 0;
}
```

I always get an error on the line which says `if (regexec(pexp, sz, MAX_MATCHES, matches, 0) == 0) {`

The error is an undefined reference to '_imp_regexec'

So I was wondering if it's because I haven't setup the linker or if the regex.h file within my include folder is the problem or maybe even something else.

Comment: Sounds like your library headers don't correspond to the standard library you're using. More details are needed about how you configured your toolchain (i.e., the IDE, the compiler(s), the standard library, etc.)

Comment: Can you compile with flags "-Wall -Werror" and see what shows up?

Comment: My ide is codeblocks

Comment: The compiler is MingW

Comment: How do I make my library headers correspond to the standard library?

Comment: The same error shows

Comment: MinGW uses Microsoft's C-Runtime (msvcrt.dll) as the C standard library. msvcrt doesn't include regular expressions, so you will have to link an additional library for that. See for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781211/c-regex-library-with-mingw)

Comment: @Felix Palmen must be correct for this code runs successfully in any "online IDE" which I've run the code on. Ideone, for example

Comment: I basically downloaded the pcre file and took the include files and lib files and placed them into the include and lib folders within MingW

Comment: And the problem still occurs

Comment: You have to link the library with `-lpcre`, maybe your IDE has an option for this

Comment: Is there any IDE which allows me to compile regex without linking libraries

Comment: That doesn't depend on the ide. You call functions that are neither in you own code nor in the standard library, so you must link against the library containing them.

Comment: Of course you could use linux or any other system with `glibc` as the standard library, `glibc` includes posix regex. But then you want curses or gtk or whatever .... find out how to link a library in your IDE or compile from the command line using the appropriate `-l` switch

Comment: Now it says the program can't start because pcre3.dll is missing from your computer.

Comment: @savagesalllll On windows, `.dll`s are searched for in the same path as the `.exe`, as well as in the system `PATH`. So, simple solution, put `pcre3.dll` in the same directory as your compiled program.