# How to use <regex.h> on windows and vscode

Tags: c, regex, windows

[error-vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUYIr.jpg)

I want to use <regex.h> in a c program. I installed MinGW-x64 from https://www.msys2.org/.
So i'm a beginner in c and i want to know what that i have to do to make my code work.

```c
#include <regex.h>

int match(const char *string, char *pattern)
{
  int status;
  regex_t re;

  if (regcomp(&re, pattern, REG_EXTENDED | REG_NOSUB) != 0)
  {
    return (0); /* Report error. */
  }
  status = regexec(&re, string, (size_t)0, NULL, 0);
  regfree(&re);
  if (status != 0)
  {
    return (0); /* Report error. */
  }
  return (1);
}

int main() {}
```

Error when i trying to compile

```
Starting build...
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\joser\Documents\projects\c\compiler.c -o C:\Users\joser\Documents\projects\c\compiler.exe
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joser\AppData\Local\Temp\ccoJSOHJ.o: in function `match':
C:\Users\joser\Documents\projects\c/compiler.c:8: undefined reference to `regcomp'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joser\Documents\projects\c/compiler.c:12: undefined reference to `regexec'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\joser\Documents\projects\c/compiler.c:13: undefined reference to `regfree'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I believe you need to add `-lregex` to your compile command. You may have to install additional packages. [C: Regex library with MinGW](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781211/c-regex-library-with-mingw)

Comment: thanks, and to stop the error on vscode?

Comment: VSCode can't prevent your code from working. Just ignore it or open the context menu and ignore it as long as your code works.